# reliableMessagingVersion in webconfig not allowed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

We have the following web.config . We want to enable reliableSessions 1.0 on our service. The reason we are using this old technique is because we want to create a mock service for an older platform we need to integrate with. This works almost as it's supposed to with the exception that we are unable to set the attribute reliableMessagingVersion. According to [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/reliablesession) it should be available on the reliableSession attribute. However, our 2019 version of visual studio complains about the attribute. I can't find any information if and when it was removed. If any one could help that would be great.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="VGBinding">
                <security mode="None" />
                <reliableSession
                    reliableMessagingVersion="WSReliableMessagingFebruary2005"
                    enabled="true"
                    ordered="true"
                    inactivityTimeout="00:03:00" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VGBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The error reported in the studio is "The reliableMessagingVersion attribute is not allowed."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether you found the answer, I am also confused.

Comment: Yes, I did. wsHttpBinding does not support that attribute but there are other HTTP bindings that do.